# How to append special character &#179; to another string in javascript without converting & to &amp;?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show a superscript to the `input` placeholder as follows:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control-file" placeholder="12 in&#179;" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = '12 in&#179;'">
```

In my js, I am creating this dom input dynamically as follows:

```
var inputelem = document.createElement('input');
var placeholderTextFromBackend = "Some text";
inputelem.classList.add("form-control-file");
inputelem.setAttribute("type", "text");
inputelem.setAttribute("placeholder", placeholderTextFromBackend + "&#179;");
inputelem.setAttribute("onfocus", "this.placeholder = ''");
inputelem.setAttribute("onblur", "this.placeholder = '12 in&#179;'");
```

But in the HTML UI, `&#179;` is getting converted to `&amp;#179;`

How to fix this and stop `&` to get automatically convert to `&amp;`?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean, it works properly for me.

Comment: Do you see the superscript `3` in placeholder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the unicode version of that character

```
var inputelem = document.createElement('input');
var placeholderTextFromBackend = "Some text";
inputelem.classList.add("form-control-file");
inputelem.setAttribute("type", "text");
inputelem.setAttribute("placeholder", placeholderTextFromBackend + "\u00B3");
inputelem.setAttribute("onfocus", "this.placeholder = ''");
inputelem.setAttribute("onblur", "this.placeholder = '12 in\u00B3'");
```